# How can i change two different nodes from two different doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, nodes, doubly-linked-list

i have 2 doubly linked list within nodes, i compare data of nodes and if data of node of second list is bigger than data of node of first list, i will chande nodes. How can i do that.

this deletes old nodes and adds that given nodes.

```
void DoubleLinkedList::SwitchNodesFromList(Node* changeNode, int index)
{
RemoveAt(index);
if (index < 0 || index > size)
    throw "Error";
if (index == 0)
{
    head = changeNode;
    if (head->next != NULL)
        head->next->prev = head;
}
else
{
    Node* prv = findPreviousByPosition(index);
    prv->next = changeNode;
    if (prv->next->next != NULL)
        prv->next->next->prev = prv->next;
 }
}
```

that keeps nodes these will change

```
 void ListController::SwitchNodes(Node* firstNodeOfList, Node* secondNodeOfList, int index)
{
Node* first = firstNodeOfList;
Node* second = secondNodeOfList;

Node* temp = first;

first->next = second->next;
first->prev = second->prev;
second->next = temp->next;
second->prev = temp->prev;
firstList->SwitchNodesFromList(second, index);
secondList->SwitchNodesFromList(first, index);
delete temp;
}
```

i compare item but i cant switch nodes

```
void ListController::CompareItemsOfNodes()
{

for (int i = 0; i < firstList->Count(); i++)
{
    if (firstList->ElementAt(i) > secondList->ElementAt(i))
    {
        ReverseList(firstList);
        
    }
    else if (firstList->ElementAt(i) == secondList->ElementAt(i))
    {
        ReverseList(secondList);
       
    }
    else if (firstList->ElementAt(i) < secondList->ElementAt(i))
    {
        SwitchNodes(firstList->GetNode(i), secondList->GetNode(i), i);
       
    }
}
}
```

[image: must be like that]

Comment: How does the code under "can't switch nodes" relate to, well, anything?

Comment: if they are two separate linked lists why are you swapping the nodes, why not swap the values

Comment: @NeonFire because that is my homework :) our teacher wants like that

Comment: @ScottHunter excuse me i couldnt understand you??

Comment: If you swap values (instead of nodes), how will any of us tell (except by inspecting your code)?  So your question is wrong?  You asked,  "how can I change two different nodes ..."

Comment: I suggest you try a simpler problem first: given a pointer to a node A, and a pointer to a node B in a list, replace B with A. `{A, P->B->Q->R} => {P->A->Q->R}`

Comment: @2785528 what do you mean?

Comment: tactical note: `at_index` functions with a linked list typically discard what makes a linked list efficient in favour of what makes a linked list inefficient. If you have to suffer O(n) to find the node in order to get O(1) insertion or removal, you've already lost.

Comment: @user4581301 what should i do

Comment: For now fix your bug. Don't worry about slow code unless it becomes a problem. Depending on the use case you may find the O(1) traversal and O(n) insert and remove of an array-like structure benefits you more than the O(n) traversal and O(1) insert and remove.

Comment: @user4581301 i dont know how to fix that.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example input and expected output? Add also the *code* to create those example lists, and the call that will execute the algorithm.

Comment: @trincot i added an image i hope that explain my question

Comment: `Node* temp = first;` - How does this variable help?